# R- Confusion on what the level in predict function means

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, prediction

I used Excel to calculate the confidence interval on a predicted value, at 95% confidence interval, so to calculate `t-value` I used function `TINV(5%,6)` thats a 2.5% and 2.5% split on each side, where 6 is degree of freedom.

But in R, the predict function, when I give `level= 0.95`, I get a different interval range, however giving `level=0.975` gives me the same answer as excel.

So, seems like in predict when you give `level=0.975`, then it takes a split of 2.5% and 2.5% on each side

But all these websites, For [example](http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-predict-new-data-values-with-r/), another [example](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/simple-linear-regression/prediction-interval-linear-regression), say we are looking for 95% confidence interval giving the formula level=0.95 (this would mean a 5% split on each side), but thats 90%, the level should be 0.975 for a 95% interval.

Whats going on? I am probabily getting confused.

---

EDIT:

`predict(model, data.frame(c= 12.75, p= 6, f=8), level = 0.975, interval = "confidence")`

The model here is a `multiple linear regression`

Data:

```
y <- c(85.10,106.30,50.20,130.60,54.80,30.30,79.40,91.00,135.40,89.30) # Total Sales

c <- c(8.50,12.90,5.20,10.70,3.10,3.50,9.20,9.00,15.10,10.20) # production cost

p <- c(5.10,5.80,2.10,8.40,2.90,1.20,3.70,7.60,7.70,4.50) # Promotion cost

f <- c(4.70,8.80,15.10,12.20,10.60,3.50,9.70,5.90,20.80,7.90) #First year box office

model <- lm(y ~ c + p + f)
```

Excel:

I have marked in yellow the forcasting in
[Excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P591Bk1VTgZFdMcmkyeTA3WjQ/view?usp=sharing)

The problem is, with Excel I get forecast of 106.72 with upper 119.35 and lower 93.36 with `=tinv(5%,6)`

With R I get forecast of 106.72 with upper at 117.7 and lower at 95.65, `level=0.95`

With `level=0.975` I get exact values as Excel.

---

In Excel:

``` =tinv(5%,6) = 2.45``Variance =  5.46 ```

`106.72 +/- tvalue*variance` : `119.35` `93.36`

In R:

`se.ci <- predi$se.fit # Value: 4.518`

`alpha <- qt((1-0.95)/2,6) # Value: -2.45`

`predi$fit[1] + c(alpha, -alpha) * se.ci # gives me 117.77165 95.65941`

As you can see the tstat value is the same but prediction is different.

But when I do this:

`alpha <- qt((1-0.975)/2,6) # Value: -2.968`

I get `93.30182 120.12924` same as excel! (Using `level=0.975` in `predict` gets me the answer, hence the confusion)

Comment: This appears to be a question just about how these R & Excel functions work. As such, it is off topic here. If you have a statistical question about confidence intervals, please edit to clarify. FWIW, I think the problem is with the Excel function; it should be `=tinv(.025, 6)`.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, do I post this again to stackoverflow or can this be moved directly?

Comment: To be on topic on [SO], it will need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). Can you provide one?

Comment: There is a statistical question here: because there is a discrepancy between how you perform a manual calculation (using Excel) and how it is done automatically in `R`, then either you are misunderstanding the calculation or making an error.  Unfortunately you haven't displayed your manual calculation explicitly, so we have little to go on.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, about that I have added more context.

Comment: In excel, I calculated the variance and tinv value http://www2.cedarcrest.edu/academic/bio/hale/biostat/session19links/tinv.html which I am sure is correct, and used formula 106.72 +/-  tinv*variance.

Comment: You don't appear to misunderstand anything.  This really is a software question, because its resolution is a matter of reading the documentation.  Excel is bizarre: it automatically splits the probability, so that `TINV(0.05,6)` is *designed* to give you the same result as `qt(1-0.05/2,6)`.